# $\sin^24x+\cos^2x=2\sin4x\cos^2x$

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

I was able to solve this using vectors but wanted to find a solution using trigonometry. Here is my solution:

$\sin^24x+\cos^2x-2\sin4x\cos x\cdot \cos x=0$.

Difference of vectors is $0$ if the vectors are both zero or they are of same magnitude and angle b/w them is $0$.

From 1st case we get $x=(2n+1)\pi/2$.

From 2nd we get no solution.

So ans is

$(2n+1)\pi/2$

Comment: Are you looking for real solutions?

Comment: What vectors are you referring to?

Comment: Hint: equivalent to $(\sin4x-\cos^2x)^2+(\cos x\sin x)^2=0$.

Comment: @J.G. thank you very much. Now it is easy as sum of squares is zero only if both the terms are zero

Comment: @JohnAlexiou The equation represens|$ā1-ā2$|  if I define |a1| as sin4x and |a2| as cosx and angle between them as x.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously at $x=n\pi$ we have $LHS\neq RHS$.  So let $t=\cot x$.  Thus $\cos^2 x=\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $\sin 4x=2\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\frac{t^2-1}{1+t^2}=\frac{4t(t^2-1)}{(t^2+1)^2}$ and we seek
$$
\left(\frac{4t(t^2-1)}{(t^2+1)^2}\right)^2+\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}=2\left(\frac{4t(t^2-1)}{(t^2+1)^2}\right)\left(\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\right)
$$
i.e.,
\begin{align*}
0&=t^2[16(t^2-1)^2+(1+t^2)^2-8t^2(t^2-1)]\\
&=t^4[17(t-t^{-1})^2 - 8 (t-t^{-1} +4].
\end{align*}
So either $t=0$ (multiplicity 2) or $t-t^{-1}=\frac2{17}[2\pm \sqrt{-13}]$ (so $t=\frac{2+\epsilon\sqrt{-13}}{17}\pm\frac1{17}\sqrt{(2+\epsilon\sqrt{-13})^2+17^2}$, $\epsilon=\pm 1$).  Finally, take the multibranch arcotangent.